# tinyMCE enable tags and disable empty paragraphs

Tags: javascript, magento, tinymce, text-editor

How to set up tinyMCE editor so, that it will not use empty paragraphs, handle all tag types (for example article, svg) and will not delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Click `Show/hide Editor` button of `WYSIWYG` so that the code is visible and then paste your html code in it and save. It will show the content properly.